# Custom code snippet type in Slack

Tags: dsl, slack, slack-api

There is a possibility to post code snippets in many programming languages in Slack:

[image]

We have a domain-specific language in our platform and it would be great to have a code snippet type in Slack with the custom code coloring scheme. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to define a custom syntax highlighting scheme. You might be better off experimenting with the ones already defined to see whether they provide any accidental pleasant highlighting of your custom DSL.

Comment: Thanks! Would be a nice feature though.